# UIButton Touch down is Too Senstive in IOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uibutton

In ScrollView I have Multiple Buttons and I am using UIControlEventTouchDown Method for each Button. Now the problem is while I am Scrolling Scrollview loadingDetail Touch Down Method called every time and page can't scroll. the same Method working  fine in IOS5 and IOS6 I am easily Scroll my Scrollview when I click on button then it goes to Detail page.Code

```
[[customCell btn1] addTarget:self action:@selector(loadingDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Any one can Guide me why UIControlEventTouchDown is too Sensitive in IOS7? How can I fix it?

Comment: Use UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Comment: i think it would me more useful for others if you add some detail in your answer.

Comment: Definitely.will update my answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Whenever you use `UIControlEventTouchDown` it means "A touch-down event in the control."

and when you use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` it means "A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control."

In your case, while scrolling a touch-down event is happened every time only because of `UIControlEventTouchDown` event. So use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event so it will only call when the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
  [[customCell btn1] addTarget:self action:@selector(loadingDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```